# How can TypeScript detect always reached or unreachable code blocks?

Tags: typescript

For example:

```js
const a = true;
if (!a) {
    // not reachable, but no warning here
}
```

Are there any ways to enable TS to check these logic errors?

Comment: Do you mean you want a linter? Have a look at [eslint](https://eslint.org/)

Comment: yes, any solutions?

Comment: Yes, use eslint

Comment: @Liam I don't think ESLint can do this kind of control flow analysis. I think it can only detect dead code after `return` not code branches that are impossible to visit.

Comment: Yeah, I've just been looking for an eslint rule and I can't find one, but this is the kind of thing a linter would do, certainly there is nothing in typescript that would disallow this code

Comment: @Liam JS linters tend to have a fairly simple analyses. OK, not to sell them short of course but they mostly deal with syntax and fairly local issues. They won't do an actual CFA to check when somethin is declared in one place and then used in another if it makes sense. The TS compiler does do more thorough checking but due to performance concerns it doesn't check too far. Classic issue is stuff like `if ("x" in foo) foo.x` vs `const hasX = "x" in foo; if (hasX) foo.x`. The latter does not compile because TS doesn't follow the references and deduce with the new context.

Comment: @VLAZ So, except linter,  are there any other ways to solve these coding issues?

Comment: @calvin1992 I'm not familiar with the full extent of TS's options. Perhaps, there is a way to make it detect dead branches of code. If not natively, then perhaps there is some third party plugin or something that uses the TS analyser. Or maybe even a different analyser.  I'm not aware of anything that will detect the situation you showed, however, that doesn't mean there isn't one. It's not too hard to make that check, the issue TS has with enabling stuff like this is that the compilation takes a lot of time and the TS team aims for speed.

Comment: fi such analysis is desired, what about const a = const_b | const_c | const_d ;
if (!a) {
    // not reachable, but no warning here
}, should it eval a first?

Comment: @ABOS as long as all the `const_*` are actually derived from some hard coded value (e.g., as opposed to `const const_x = prompt("enter something") === "hello"` then it's possible to analyse it statically and deduce whether `if (!a)` leads to a dead branch or not. IntelliJ IDEA has an amazing analysis system over Java codebases that can detect *vastly* more complex and longer chains of calls and value derivation that span the entire codebase. I doubt a simple constant assignment is outside of the bounds of analysis. The question is: 1. whether it's implemented. 2. does it run in acceptable time

Comment: @VLAZ, so you are saying a will be evaluated statically if const_b,c,d are hardcoded?

Comment: @ABOS it *can* be evaluated statically. I'm not sure TS will do that. At least not by default. However, it's certainly possible to do it.

Comment: @VLAZ, I do understand that it can be analyzed statically, the question is what is the boundary that it should do so, what about a function returns hardcoded const, should it be evaluated?

Comment: @ABOS that's an odd question. Let me reiterate it *can*. Again, IntelliJ IDEA does it with Java code. Yes, including methods returning booleans. You can get a warning for calling `if (isSomething())` and `isSomething()` can be determined to always return `false`. To me, preventing *more* potential problems is better, so "yes". Yet the way you're asking it leads me to suspect you expect me to say "no". As before, the limiting factors here are whether somebody as actually done this analyser and is that analysis runs fast enough to useful as you develop.